# error when trying to install Exchange 2016 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, exchange-2016

I'm trying to install the from msdn downloaded Exchange Server 2016 on a Windows Server 2016 OS. 
Problem is, I get the Error-Message

> the windows component server-gui-mgmt-infra isn't installed on this computer

I checked everything and it says, I need to download the cumulative update 4 for exchange server. When I now try to get it on microsoft-site I'm getting an error 404 (I know, the site isn't there anymore). 
But: Is there any other way to get an installable version of Exchange 2016? All links redirect to microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem with using the cumulative update 8. Found it coincidentally: https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=56363